# Android NetworkOnMainThreadException when calling Url.OpenStream

Tags: java, android, url, exception, networkonmainthread

I get this exception  when running my code on emulator (Android 4.0.3 / API 15). While opening a stream it will throw an exception. Error-message is `null`.

```
try {
    String adress        = "xxx";
    URL url              = new URL(adress);
    InputSource source   = new InputSource(url.openStream());

} catch (Exception e) {
    (new TextView).setText("Error: "+e.getMessage());
}
```

URL is still working with the emulator (in browser).

I have cleaned the project.

Also Internet connection is allowed:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Exception : `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Comment: Did you try with a real address?

Comment: what kind of exception?

Comment: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please **never** run a networking operation on the main (**UI**) thread .

**Main** thread is used to:

- interact with user.
- render UI components.

any long operation on it may risk your app to be closed with **ANR** message.

Take a look at the following :

- [Keeping your application Responsive](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html)
- [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

you can easily use an `AsyncTask` or a `Thread` to perform your network operations.

Here is a great tutorial about threads and background work in android: [Link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

*Manifest.xml:*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

---

*.java:*

```
private static boolean DEVELOPER_MODE = true;
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     if (DEVELOPER_MODE) {
         StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                 .detectDiskReads()
                 .detectDiskWrites()
                 .detectNetwork()   // or .detectAll() for all detectable problems
                 .penaltyLog()
                 .build());
         StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                 .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
                 .detectLeakedClosableObjects()
                 .penaltyLog()
                 .penaltyDeath()
                 .build());
     }  
...
```

hope it helps.

see also : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html