# Unable to fetch data from a URL and display it inside a Textview

Tags: android

I am trying to learn to fetch data from a URL and display it inside a textview.
The code doesn't show any error but on executing it displays an empty screen.

I am unable to understand why it's not entering inside the while loop.

Here is the code..

```
 MainActivity.java


package com.example.asad.read;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      Log.d("asd","calling call");
        call();

    }

    public void call() {
        int count = 0;
        StringBuffer sb = null;
    Log.d("asd","above try");
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

//            URLConnection tc = url.openConnection();
//            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
//                    tc.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            Log.d("asd","inside try");
            while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                if (count == 2)
                    break;
                Log.d("asd","inside while");
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append("\n");
                count++;
            }
            bf.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
        tv.setText(sb.toString());


    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android, it is discouraged to perform network operations on the UI thread. [See this link](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html).

In your example, you are calling openStream from onCreate which is called in UI thread. Please try to create an async task and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to perform the URL.openStream and reading of the contents on the stream in the background, rather in the UI thread.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15685887/532670) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

First of all *you're doing something very wrong*... **network call with the UI/Main Thread.**

Then you are using  `StringBuffer sb`  without instantiating it.

Last but not least you are **not trapping the URL exception**...

You should really look at the console for compile errors before posting it here...